# NavigationMixin invalid type after deployment

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, navigationmixin.navigate

I have created and deployed a LWC component in a lightning experience page, that when clicked navigates to an other (newly created) experience page page with the following call:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'comm__namedPage',
    attributes: {
      name: 'My_Page__c'
});
```

I used SFDX to deploy the experience pages and the component to a different sandbox and suddenly I see the message: "Invalid Page" when clicking the button. I have double checked the api-name (which is the same as in the working sandbox) and also tried to debug with:

```
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
    type: 'comm__namedPage',
    attributes: {
      name: 'My_Page__c'
    }
}).then((generatedUrl) => {
    console.log('generated url: ' + generatedUrl);
});
```

which prints out:

> generated url: null

I have googled and tried several things (e.g. adding an actionName) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I am sure, page not deployed, may i know how did u deploy Experiences pages?  i would recommend deploy experiencebundle.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found the solution. It turned out to be a caching issue. Apparently all routes are cached and even a browser restart did not help so it's probably inside the storage/cookie. It seems like deploying a page with SFDX doesn't refresh the cache. Switching to a private window did work.

Thanks for the tips everyone.